# Let $f:(X, \mathfrak T_X) \rightarrow (Y, \mathfrak T_Y)$ be a continuous function. Then $f(Cl(A) = Cl(f(A))$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:(X, \mathfrak T_X) \rightarrow (Y, \mathfrak T_Y)$ be a continuous function.  Then $f(Cl(A) = Cl(f(A))$.

My definition of closure is:
Let $(X,\mathfrak T)$ be a topological space and let $ A \subseteq X$ . The closure of $A$ is $Cl(A) = \bigcap \{U \subseteq X: U$ is a closed set and $A \subseteq U\}$ 
Based on this I know $A \subseteq Cl(A)$

My definition of continuous is "A function $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is said to be continous if for each open subset $V$ of $ \mathbb R,  f^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$.

I am supposed to determine if this is true or false and if true prove it and if false give a counterexample. I have the definitions but I really do not even know where to start.  I have all the relevant definitions gathered but do not know where to go from here.

Comment: I think you want the union in the definition of closure to be an intersection

Comment: @ZachEffman I edited.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Is it true when $f$ is an inclusion?  Consider a few examples.

Comment: I am not sure what an inclusion is

Comment: @AlyssaWallace An inclusion is when $X$ is a subspace of $Y$.  For example, the $x$-axis includes into the $xy$-plane.

Comment: Is this a false statement without inclusion?

Comment: @AlyssaWallace Let me be clear: look at a few inclusions.  Keep looking and you will find a counterexample.

Comment: after trying to look back at my book... I have no examples of continuous functions for this topic.  My only examples are piece-wise functions. Any suggestions of where to look?

Comment: @AlyssaWallace Any inclusion of a subspace is a continuous function.  There are also simple functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that are counterexamples.  Just write down lots of examples.